# Rule and benefits of joining feet's together during solat

Tags: hadith, salat, sunnah, obligation

Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu

Please if anyone can help me with this question I will appreciate it

What are the rules I mean is it compulsory to join feet's during prayer

When I was young I use to hear that shaytan use to pass through the gap between you and your partner in solat if you don't join your feet and make you prayer invalid is it true

Please I need more evidence please

Jazakumul llahu khayran

Comment: Do you mean putting your feet next and close to that of your neighbor in the row while praying in congregation? This might have a basis in the sunnah however the thing which has a stronger evidence is standing in the row shoulder by shoulder or let's say arms close to each other. This is regarded by most madhhabs as wajib or close to that.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it